# Reason to use DECIMAL(31,0)

Tags: mysql, oracle, decimal, sqldatatypes

What is the reason that some people from Oracle background are using DECIMAL(31,0) for integers. In MySQL it is not efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle implements the "INTEGER" ANSI datatype as a synonym for NUMBER(38)

For more details see "[Learn Oracle: Datatypes for SQL and PL/SQL, Numbers](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/oracle-guide/learn-oracle-datatypes-for-sql-and-plsql-numbers-10673)"

However, the following table should be used as a mapping between datatype in Oracle and MySQL:

["Oracle® Database SQL Developer Supplementary Information for MySQL Migrations"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#BABICBGE)

*Oracle and MySQL Compared > Data Types > Comparing Data Types*

The main difference, as explained [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22289) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html) is that Oracle NUMBER datatype is variable-length format while MySQL DECIMAL(n) datatype used to be `represented as strings that require one byte per digit or sign character` (before version 5.0.3)

> **(Oracle NUMBER Datatype) Internal Numeric Format**
>
> Oracle Database stores numeric data in
>   variable-length format. Each value is
>   stored in scientific notation, with 1
>   byte used to store the exponent and up
>   to 20 bytes to store the mantissa. The
>   resulting value is limited to 38
>   digits of precision. Oracle Database
>   does not store leading and trailing
>   zeros. For example, the number 412 is
>   stored in a format similar to 4.12 x
>   102, with 1 byte used to store the
>   exponent(2) and 2 bytes used to store
>   the three significant digits of the
>   mantissa(4,1,2). Negative numbers
>   include the sign in their length.
>
> Taking this into account, the column
>   size in bytes for a particular numeric
>   data value NUMBER(p), where p is the
>   precision of a given value, can be
>   calculated using the following
>   formula:
>
> `ROUND((length(p)+s)/2))+1`
>
> where s equals zero if the number is
>   positive, and s equals 1 if the number
>   is negative.
>
> Zero and positive and negative
>   infinity (only generated on import
>   from Oracle Database, Version 5) are
>   stored using unique representations.
>   Zero and negative infinity each
>   require 1 byte; positive infinity
>   requires 2 bytes.

and

> **(MySQL) DECIMAL Data Type Changes**
>
> The storage requirements for the
>   integer and fractional parts of each
>   value are determined separately. Each
>   multiple of nine digits requires four
>   bytes, and any remaining digits left
>   over require some fraction of four
>   bytes. [...]
>
> For example, a DECIMAL(18,9) column
>   has nine digits on either side of the
>   decimal point, so the integer part and
>   the fractional part each require four
>   bytes. A DECIMAL(20,6) column has
>   fourteen integer digits and six
>   fractional digits. The integer digits
>   require four bytes for nine of the
>   digits and three bytes for the
>   remaining five digits. The six
>   fractional digits require three bytes.